# convert into hash code and decrypt it

Tags: c#, asp.net, hashcode

I pass a loan ID, social security number and zipcode in url.

```
LoanID: 205689
ssn No: 555-896-4569
Zip code: 12345
```

the url is `http://localhost/Product/abc/manager/internet/PayCredential.aspx?LoanID=205689`

I need to convert the social security number and zip code into a hashcode for security purposes and pass them in this url. I would then decrypt them when the page is called. How can I do this?

Comment: Hashing is a one way process. You want encryption, which is a two-way process.

Comment: I hope SSN you posted is not a real one.

Comment: Downvoting, since someone helped you and you didn't respond to them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother reinventing the wheel. Use SSL - all your communications will be encrypted, including your URLs.

Comment: Except that SSL will not prevent the guy standing behind me from seeing my SSN in the browser address bar.  Thats a pretty epic fail in a banking app (which I can only assume this is).

Comment: The guy standing behind you can also see what you type, or the SSN somewhere else on the screen.

Comment: Not if it is entered into a password field.

Answer (score 0):

Hasing wont work in your case. You cannot access the object from its hashed value. You should encrypt the data before you send and decrypt it before you use. Here you can see an example of how to use encrpyt and decrypt in c#: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C

plus you can use https for more security.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole approach is wrongheaded.  Under no circumstances should you be passing that information via the querystring, even if you are encrypting it using SSL.  As I mention in the comment to @zmbq, I don't want someone shoulder surfing my SSN while I'm paying my mortgage, thanks.

What you should do is have the data securely stored on the server side, SSL secure your connection, and the client's URL should only use a non-identifiable token (like session ID) to refer to it.  If the user needs to enter their SSN as part of their login identifier, it should be entered via a password field so that the browser masks the input.